# Javascript toISOString Format

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, format, iso

The `.toISOString()` function in JS is giving me string like this:

`2015-06-14T20:00:00:000Z`

I need it to be like this:

`2015-06-14T20:00:00Z`

Is there any alternate function in JS that returns a date in that format? Or do I need to write my own function to do it?

Thanks, all!

Comment: just adjust it:  `date.toISOString().replace(/:\d{3}Z$/g,"Z")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in JavaScript method that returns a date in that format.  You could write your own function or you could use [momentjs format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/).

`moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss[Z]")`

Comment: Thanks, coderfin. I discovered this just before you posted ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, dandavis.

I went with [moment.js](http://momentjs.com). I found that the `format()` function in moment actually prints it the way I wanted.